# Logstash: Nginx access logs agent field conflicts with ECS default agent field

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, logstash, elk

I am trying to include agent field from Nginx access logs using the `useragent`
filter in Logstash to get client operating system data in ES, but the LS ingests the Filebeat related data to ES in the `agent` field, actually I am OK if the Filebeat (agent) related data not to be ingested in ES, how can I make Logstash to ingest Nginx agent field data instead of the Filebeat, below is the Logstash pipeline that I using.

```
       input {
          beats {
            port => 5044
          }
        }

        filter {
            grok {
                match => { "message" => "%{IPORHOST:clientip} - %{DATA:user_name} \[%{HTTPDATE:time}\] \"%{WORD:method}%{DATA:url} HTTP/%{NUMBER:http_version}\" %{NUMBER:response_code} %{NUMBER:body_sent:bytes} \"%{DATA:referrer}\" \"%{DATA:agent}\"" }
            }

            if [response_code] == "404" {
                mutate {
                    add_tag => ["error"]
                }
            }


            if [response_code] == "401" {
                mutate {
                    add_tag => ["security"]
                }
            }

            if [response_code] == "403" {
                mutate {
                    add_tag => ["security"]
                }
            }

            useragent {
              source => "agent"
              target => "client_user_agent"
            }

            if [clientip] =~ "^10\..*" or [clientip] =~ "^127\..*" or [clientip] =~ "^192.168\..*" or [clientip] == "0.0.0.0" {
                mutate {
                    add_tag => ["internal"]
                }
            }


            if "internal" not in [tags] {
                geoip {
                    default_database_type => "City"
                    source => "clientip"
                    target => "geo"
                    tag_on_failure => ["geoip-city-failed"]
                }
                geoip {
                    default_database_type => "ASN"
                    source => "clientip"
                    target => "geo"
                    tag_on_failure => ["geoip-asn-failed"]
                }
            } else {
                mutate {
                    remove_field => ["[geo]"]
                }
            }
        }

        output {
          elasticsearch {
            hosts => "${TEST_ES_HOSTS}"
```

Comment: @Val can you help me with this?